# How does Matt L. do to remain over the top?

Tags: discussion, tags

[The initial pun turned into a look at observable variables showing trends and clustering]

Outlier detection is a radical task in signal processing. The user [Matt L.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/4298/matt-l) has about three times more  total reputation and year reputation than the second best.

- What are his secrets?
- How can they benefit to the average crowd?

Nota: I was thinking about proposing a [humour](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humour) tag. There was a DSP humor cartoon contest at ICASSP 2000. This meta post is a way to test the sensitivity of the audience:

[image: Dirty DSP talk]

Comment: :-) Darn fine question! @Matt L. is a great resource for SP.SE users.

Comment: Hey, this is about me! Only saw it just now. I guess the answer is not hanging around Meta too much :)

Comment: A comment which deserves becoming an answer, I guess :)

Comment: Is he a John Skeet or a Don Bradman?

Comment: No, I cannot think to that level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer a lot and answer well? Some statistics:

[image: Top 20]
*Figure 1. Number of answers and reputation of all-time top 20 users, with a trendline fit to the data.*

Comment: Quite impressive results. What I like with regression and intercept, is that one could get reputation without answering :)

Comment: Yes, but you may have to be in the top 20 for that! Was it 100 rep that you get if "we trust you on other stackexchange sites".

Comment: Nicely done, @OlliNiemitalo!  Thanks for your graphs, and stirring @Laurent into action. :-)

Comment: Who is taking care now of @Matt L. advice: "the answer is not hanging around Meta too much" :)

Comment: Based on my observations, this would be the correct answer. Matt L answers a *lot* of questions, but he also provides excellent answers. I gave up trying to keep up with his reputation count a long time ago. :)

Comment: @JasonR Let me acknowledge your authoritative comment by validating this answer.

Answer (score 3):

As I am studying dimension reduction methods, @OlliNiemitalo answer triggered my curiosity. I pushed the study to rank 30, and the answer/reputation graph looks like:

[image: Answers-reputation graph]

No drastic change in the trend. However, more points cluster at the bottom. So I tried with other easy to reach variables: Reputation, #Month (of presence), #Answers, #Questions, #PeopleReached. The question/reputation graph possibly rules out the number of questions as a fine variable:

[image: Questions-reputation graph]

Then, going to 3D, we can try answer/month/reputation:

[image: Answers-month-reputation graph]

or answer/reach/reputation:

[image: Answers-reach-reputation graph]

Those 3D graphs seem to display a bended shape, which clusters when projected in 2D. The crowd of visionaries (early adopters) is quite apparent from the figures.  Time matters a bit  apparently. But there should be hidden variables. I hope    I am not  wasting your time (and mine) on this. I am not sure this deserves higher-order nonlinear  dimension reduction techniques.

Comment: Beautiful graphs !

Comment: Very cool! Thanks for the analysis. :-)